# Node.js not loading AngularJS views

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I was developing an web application just like that:

```
- project
--- app
------ controllers
------ views
------ app.js
--- public
------ assets
--------- css
--------- js
--------- img
--- index.html
```

... inside my index.html I had the basics html, link, script tags. All that loading the angular application and everything was working fine.

But now, I need to loading all the application using Node.js.

So first I move the index.html to public/ and created a new file.

**index.js (Node.js)**

```
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Runing the Node.js I got at the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/app/views/layouts/public.html 404 (Not Found)
```

This is how I load my angular views

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider, stateHelperProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

  stateHelperProvider.state({
    name: 'public',
    title: 'Home',
    url: '/',
    controller: 'PublicCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/layouts/public.html',
    data: {
      requireLogin: false
    }
  })
  .state({
    name: 'private',
    controller: 'PrivateCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/layouts/private.html',
    data: {
      requireLogin: true
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: 'browse',
        title: 'Home',
        url: '/browse',
        templateUrl: '/app/views/browse/index.html',
        controller: 'BrowseCtrl'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't see where you instructed node.js to serve your views.

Comment: I don't, I just instructed the node.js to index.html. The rest should be continue work which is don't.

Comment: if you don't instruct node.js to serve it, it won't.

Comment: The index.html and the static files is working thanks to @Olly. But the router views is not.

Comment: Right, those are the ones i'm talking about.

Comment: My bad!!! Just add ```app.use("/app", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));``` and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

This worked for me, I've only used app.use for the static content (as you are) like css and js.

Also you've written it as though your index.html is in your public directory

Hope this helps

Comment: Is that in your console of the browser? Sounds like that's because it can't find your css stuff. In the path to public files try just `assets/blah` instead of `./assets/blah`. Also is it finding your html file now? :)

Comment: Sorry, the static files worked, but know I have this: ```GET http://localhost:3000/app/views/layouts/public.html 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need those top 2 lines, they just make things more complicated... atleast from what I can see. It's getting confused about looking within app/views which maybe is because of your 2nd line. Absolutely no idea where the /layouts/ is coming from. Is this in Node console or browser console?

Comment: Why are you looking for a public.html? Where is that even from? Is your Index.html page loading? EDIT: Ignore me are you just including a view. Perhaps remove the /layouts/ from the GET request?

Comment: /layouts/ is from the angular route... check the update

Comment: Hmm, I don't know much about angular routing unfortunately - but atleast the html page is appearing with assets now. Is this the only error you're getting? I can keep trying to work it out, but i'm afraid I might not be the best help!

Comment: I don't know if you meant that, but just add ```app.use("/app", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));``` worked.

Comment: Ahh perfect! Would you mind accepting this answer then? Not sure why we both have downvotes though...